# About LoRa Remote Environmental Monitoring

Tags: lora, remote

I'm currently working on designing a wireless communication system for remote environmental monitoring, aiming to gather data from an open area approximately 1 kilometer away. The system needs to reliably transmit data at a rate of 100KB per second to enable real-time monitoring of environmental parameters.

To achieve this, I'm planning to employ LoRa (Long-Range Low-Power Radio Frequency) technology to ensure a stable connection over long distances. Here are more detailed parameters and requirements.

System Components and Parameters:

```
Transmitter Device: I'm considering using a LoRa transmitter module, such as the Semtech SX1276, operating in the 868MHz or 915MHz frequency bands.
Receiver Device: I intend to use a compatible LoRa receiver module to capture the remotely transmitted data.
Transmission Distance: The data transmission distance is approximately 1 kilometer, and I need to account for the impact of terrain and obstacles on the signal.
Data Rate: A data rate of 100KB per second is required to ensure the accuracy of real-time monitoring data.
```

Power and Configuration:

Transmit Power: I plan to use an appropriate transmit power on the transmitter device to balance communication range and battery life. The initial consideration for transmit power is 10-20dBm.
Coding and Modulation Scheme: I will utilize suitable coding and modulation schemes to enhance data immunity to interference and overall reliability.
Receiver Sensitivity: I need to configure appropriate sensitivity on the receiver device to effectively capture weak signals at long distances.

Software Configuration and Management:

LoRaWAN Protocol: I'm considering implementing the LoRaWAN protocol for managing communication between devices, providing improved connection stability and flexibility.
Management Platform: I intend to employ a LoRaWAN network server to manage devices, monitor data transmission, and perform remote configuration.

Given these parameters, could you kindly offer advice on how to select the suitable frequency band, power settings, and configure the LoRaWAN protocol within the context of LoRa technology? Additionally, if you have any recommendations for alternative technologies applicable to this application, please provide those as well.

Comment: The baudrate and real-time requirements don't sound feasible given the range. LoRa isn't a suitable technology for hard real-time applications, it's more suitable for "hit or miss" applications that aren't timing-critical, such as sensors periodically sending out data with long intervals in between.

Comment: A kilometer in an urban cavern differs from a rural hilltop kilometer. The RF noise floor and adjacent interferers differs too.

Comment: Thanks, based on my parameters, what modifications can be made